# Merge files with seperator

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to merge a bunch of `.JSON` files into one `.JSON` file from a batch file.

Everything works, but I want the script to seperate each files content with a comma.

```
copy *_MODIFIED.JSON WIP_CombinedJSON.JSON
```

I can't figure out how to do that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `for` loop and use `type` to read the files. This allows you to add custom separators.

The flag variable is to prevent adding a separator at the beginning. The first line after `@echo off` is to start with a empty file.

```
@echo off
> WIP_CombinedJSON.JSON type nul
set "flag="
for %%A in (*_MODIFIED.JSON) do (
    if defined flag echo ,
    type "%%~A"
    set flag=1
) >> WIP_CombinedJSON.JSON
```